# XNA: DrawUserPrimitives - Drawing FILLED rectangles

Tags: c#, xna, primitive

I have a working line drawing code going using "DrawUserPrimitives"
I have set up a function to "draw a rectangle" using a linestrip and VectorPositionColor

```
VertexPositionColor[] lineVertices = new VertexPositionColor[5];
lineVertices[0].Position = new Vector3(inMidPoint.X - halfWidth, inMidPoint.Y - halfLength, 0);
lineVertices[0].Color = inLineColor;
```

etc..

```
basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
mGraphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, lineVertices, 0, lineVertices.Length - 1);
```

Using this method I can create the colored outline of a rectangle. Now, how can I fill in that rectangle with a color, using this system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TriangleStrip instead of LineStrip - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.primitivetype.aspx

Comment: When you switched to using PrimitiveType.LineStrip, did you have to change the call to mGraphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.LineStrip, lineVertices, 0, lineVertices.Length - 1); ?